# Artifact on a custom bullet with Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have implemented a collapsible menu with a triangle bullet on expandable items. The triangle rotates when the link is clicked and sub-menus items are expanded.

The problem is that with internet explorer there is this light dotted line to the left of my bullet. It appears when I expand the item and disappear when I click somewhere else on the page.

[image]

It corresponds to nothing in my style sheet. Any idea how I can get rid of it?

This is how the bullet is styled:

```
#block-menu-menu-intra-acp-menu li.expanded > a{
    padding-left:12px;
    background: url('images/triangle_bullet_down.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be it, but try setting `outline: 0;` on your `a`?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the focus outline. You can disable it with `outline: 0`, but try to provide some other indication of keyboard focus to your users.